# Content-disposition replacement for local files

Tags: html, hyperlink, network-programming, download, filesystems

I am working on a web page that will be on a local or network filesystem.  What I would like to do is have have the user click a link to a file and start a save as dialog.  However, since the webpage and the file are both on a local or network filesystem, I cannot control the header.

Is there any sort of workaround?

Thanks,
Grae

Comment: What browser(s) will be used? Chrome has a download attribute (http://codebits.glennjones.net/downloadattr/downloadattr.htm). In other browsers you could use AJAX to load the resource, and then use JS to base64 encode it and create a data url from it. In the data url you can specify the MIME type you want. Then use window.open(dataurl) to trigger the download. The only problem might be binary data files in older/IE browsers, but I'm not sure

Comment: @Gerben How would I use base64?  Does this have to be a server side operation?  Even if I converted the file to base64, how to I start the download dialog from the client side?

Comment: you can base64 encode at the client side (you don't have a server as you said in your question). There are some JS libraries to add base64 functions to IE7. You trigger the download by using a MIME type like `application/octet-stream` and a window.open, or just a normal link.